# Salt value in OpenID Connect Session Management

Tags: openid-connect

I am using the https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html specification to develop openid connect session management. According to the specification we have to split the session_state to get the salt value at the OP iframe side as below.

```
`var salt = session_state.split('.')[1];`
```

But the session_state value I'm obtaining from the RP is a String a value. It does not contain any '.' So what I need to know is should I pass a salt value from RP to OP with the format 'session_state.salt'? Otherwise how can I split the session_state value from '.'? I'm bit confused with the salt value. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `session_state` is a value for session management purposes that is generated by the OP and passed to the RP in the initial authentication response. The OP gets that value back by the OP iframe that is served by the RP but points to content that is being served by the OP. The non-normative sample uses a salt and a "." character but that is implementation specific and by no means is something that the RP is aware of.

IOW. the OP gets back a value that it generated itself and it would know what to do with it. It seems that you assume that the OP iframe contains content that the RP generates, but that is not the case.

Comment: I'm passing a cookie(which creates when OP is in login status)  from OP to RP at the authentication response. And I'm sending the same cookie as the session_state variable from RP to OP. From the OP I have the direct access to the cookie.  So then I'm planning to compare the cookie which I got from RP as session_state with the cookie which I read directly from the OP without using any salt values. Is my approach correct? Please advice me on this. Thanks

Comment: assuming that you want to deal with multiple RPs that's not a good way of implementing session_state: Client ID and source origin URL should be added to the session state calculation; why not stay close to the non-normative example?